# Url rewriting in asp.net 3.5

Tags: asp.net

I am developing an asp.net 3.5 application.I need to rewrite the url.My current url is,

http://app.evetos.com/Areas/UserV1/Controllers/Order1.aspx?EventID=JRQlVFOQDYs=&status1=true

This url will be very long and not user freindly.So i need to reduce this url to following url,

http://app.evetos.com/Order/G8Oh9WHyAKA=/true

Here,querystrings like EventID and status are dynamically generating.So we need to pass these querystrings dynamically.so we can't hardcode these values.

We tried  tag in web.config.but it is not useful.because here we cant pass the dynamic values in web.config.

So please tell me,how to do this.is there any application in internet please give me the url.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help, but maybe someone in the future can use this. We use the following code for our URL rewrites:

```
private void ProcessRequestedURL()
    {
        string paths = "|site|pages|from|navigation|go|here|"; // Follow the format of |xxx|xxx|...|
        string[] parts = Request.Path.Split('/');

        if (paths.ToLower().Contains("|" + parts[1].ToLower() + "|") && !parts[2].Contains(".") && !parts[2].ToLower().Contains("presentations"))
        {
            string page = null;
            string directory = null;
            string request = null;
            string rewriteUrl = null;

            directory = parts[1];
            page = parts[2];
            request = Regex.Replace(Request.Path, string.Concat("/", directory, "/", page, "/"), "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

            rewriteUrl = "/";
            if (parts[1].ToLower() != "vgm") // special case.  "vgm" means site root.
            {
                rewriteUrl += string.Concat(directory, "/");
            }

            if (File.Exists(string.Concat(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath, rewriteUrl, page, ".aspx")))
            {
                rewriteUrl += string.Concat("", page, ".aspx?req=", request);
                Context.RewritePath(rewriteUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                rewriteUrl = string.Concat("/404Error.aspx?aspxerrorpath=", page, ".aspx&req=", request);
                Context.Response.StatusCode = 404;
                Context.Response.Redirect(rewriteUrl);
            }               
        }
    } `
```